# Exercício - Cálculo de bhaskará

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
a=int(input("Digite o valor de A: "))

b=int(input("Digite o valor de B: "))

c=int(input("Digite o valor de C: "))

delta=float(((b**2)-4*a*c))

r1=float((-b +(delta ** (1/2))/2)

r2=float((-b -(delta ** (1/2))/2)


if delta > 0

    print("Temos duas raizes reais e distintas. \nRaiz 1: {} \nRaiz 2:{}".format(r1,r2))

elif delta = 0

    print("Temos duas raízes iguais. \nRaiz 1: {} \nRaiz 2: {}".format(r1,r2))
elif delta < 0

    print("Raizes inexistentes.")
```

Erro:

> r2=float((-b -(delta ** (1/2))/2)
>
> ```
>  ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Qual seria o erro? ele fala ser na linha 6, que é a do r2, mas não vejo nada que interfira no código.

Comment: Seus parênteses estão desbalanceados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que na linha do `r1` e do `r2` você não fechou os parênteses do `float`. Veja abaixo:

**Original:**

```
r1=float((-b +(delta ** (1/2))/2)
r2=float((-b -(delta ** (1/2))/2)
```

**Modificado:**

```
r1=float((-b +(delta ** (1/2))/2))
r2=float((-b -(delta ** (1/2))/2))
```

**Outros erros:**

No bloco das condicionais, você esqueceu de iniciar os blocos de código com **":"** e no primeiro bloco `elif` você colocou um sinal de atribuição (=) ao invés de usar um operador de comparação (==).

O correto deveria ser:

```
if delta > 0:
    print("Temos duas raizes reais e distintas. \nRaiz 1: {} \nRaiz 2:{}".format(r1,r2))

elif delta == 0:
    print("Temos duas raízes iguais. \nRaiz 1: {} \nRaiz 2: {}".format(r1,r2))

elif delta < 0:
    print("Raizes inexistentes.")
```

Um outro problema que seu código possui nas linhas 17 e 19 é que em alguns cálculos, você obterá o erro `TypeError: can't convert complex to float`. Isso ocorre porque em alguns cálculos, o delta pode ter um valor negativo e o programa irá calculá-lo usando potenciação. Para resolver isso, você deve fazer uma verificação do delta antes de calcular as raízes.

Comment: Jean, cite também o problema com os números complexos, não resolva este problema! porém mostre o caminho de como consertar ou de onde procurar a solução.

Comment: Problema com os números complexos ? Está falando de que exatamente ?

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/BJJEUWSXS

Comment: Putz eu não tinha reparado nisso porque eu não tinha executado o código kkk. Obrigado por avisar, eu vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas pessoal, irei estudar melhor a linguagem.